# PHP PDO MySQL SELECT EXISTS

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, pdo

how can I do a `SELECT EXISTS` in php pdo?

Here is my code:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = :username OR :email)");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt) {
    echo "Sorry your username or email is already taken. please try again";
} else {
    echo "Success!";
}
```

but the code does not echo out anything.

Comment: `$stmt = prepare(` is probably your mistake... `$stmt = $dbh -> prepare(`

Comment: @RoiEX sorry, just edited the op. i did put that, just forgot to write it but it does not work.

Comment: If there is no error message printed out either, you might check if you are echoing your message inside a tag; echo '<form'/* your code */ echo ' class="something">'

Comment: @RoiEX I've tried `header` it looks. its just giving me a blank page.

Comment: What do you mean by "using header"? Why are you even using such a statement if you just could use `SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = :username OR :email` + `if($stmt -> rowCount() > 0){/*not available*/}`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want In:

```
Where username in (:username, :email)
```